# ldap_bind() not working

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to use PHP to verify authentication in our Active Directory using LDAP.

I know a valid username and password, our domain, and LDAP server.

`$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver)` works, it returns a 'ldap link' resource.

But when I call `ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $password)` it fails.

I have tried a lot of settings for `$ldaprdn`, but can't find one that works. Some examples:

`$ldaprdn = $username;`

`$ldaprdn = $username.'@'.$domain;`

`$ldaprdn = $domain.'\\'.$username;`

`$ldaprdn = "uid=$username,cn=users,dc=$ldapserver,dc=$domain,dc=com"`

`$ldaprdn = "uid=$username,dc=$domain,dc=com"`

`$ldaprdn = "uid=$username,dc=com"`

`$ldaprdn = "uid=$username,dc=$domain"`

Nothing of that works, `ldap_error($ldapconn)` always returns "Invalid credentials".

Login and password are obviously right, I'm able to login in Windows. Any idea what I could use?

Comment: Our AD domain is like "mydomain.intranet", should it be something like dc=intranet instead of dc=com? or dc=mydomain,dc=intranet? I'll try these tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging this sort of thing is really tricky. Use the logs on the LDAP server if you have access, or try something like http://jxplorer.org/ to get better information about the actual dn/context of the user you are trying to connect as. You probably have part of it missing or not quite right.

Also, if your username/password has characters that need escaping on the command line, make sure you are not escaping them in the PHP script.

Comment: Thanks for reply. They need no escape it's alphanumeric, and I print `$ldaprdn` and it's what expected. I saw some examples when it's really username@domain, I'm starting to think it's related to apache/php module.